# Is there any language where there exist words for smells not connected with smelling objects?

Tags: etymology, list-of-languages

Is there any language where there exist words for smells not derived or already disconnected from words for smelling objects?

For instance, those derived from verbs, of obscure etymology, or not having the corresponding noun in the contemporary language?

For other feelings there are:

***bitter*** - from a verb

***yellow*** - ***gholtos*** apparently already meant yellow color at PIE stage

***sweet*** - ***su̯ea̯dus*** already meant "sweet" in PIE

***red*** - ***e̯roudhros*** already meant "red" in PIE

***sour*** - from PIE word for cheese ***seuros***, but long forgotten since.

I am looking for words meaning particular smells, not just "good smell" or "bad smell".

Comment: Your last sentence makes sense, but I have no idea what you're trying to say with your first two sentences!

Comment: @curiousdannii I suspect there are no special words for smells in any language except "smell of X" because the number of various smell receptors is very high (hundreds of various receptors) compared to the limited number of basic tastes and colors. So each object usually has own smell and they usually do not coincide. I want to prove or disprove the conjecture.

Comment: True for anybody who knows some science there are technically only five tastes (sweet, sour, bitter, umami, salt), but for a few billion other people there's a vast number, because except for anosmics we experience taste as a combination of inputs from the tongue and nose, but are not aware of it.

Comment: @hippietrail "umami" is not a basic taste. It was popularized, I think, due to marketing considerations. It is an "exstended" taste, like say, taste of strawberry or a conifer.

Comment: @hippietrail "we experience taste as a combination of inputs from the tongue and nose, but are not aware of it" - wrong.

Comment: "True for anybody who knows some science " - source please.

Comment: So you are saying that basically everybody in the world, when they talk about taste are only talking about sweet, sour, bitter, salt, and combinations of those? If so, source please.

Comment: @hippietrail I never said this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to research by Asifa Majid and Niclas Burenhult, there are some languages that use more abstract odor words, see [Odors expressible in language, as long as you speak right language](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2014/01/140103085248.htm). It appears that speakers of [Jahai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahai_language) can describe odors with the same ease as colors: “Majid and Burenhult found that Jahai speakers could name odors with the same conciseness and level of agreement as colors, but English speakers struggled to name odors.”

At [Warum Gerüche so unbeschreiblich sind (srf.ch)](http://www.srf.ch/wissen/mensch/warum-gerueche-so-unbeschreiblich-sind), there is an example word from Jahai: *pʔus* describes the odor that is found in old rice, boiled cabbage, mushrooms and some hornbill birds.

Majid and Burenhult speculate that the ability of Jahai speakers to precisely name odors is determined by their culture. It comes from the importance of the odors in their everyday life as hunters and gatherers in the Malay Peninsula rainforest.

Answer (score 0):

English has at least a couple of words that seem to meet your criteria (the definitions below are from American Heritage Dictionary):

***pungent*** "Affecting the organs of taste or smell with a sharp acrid sensation", from Latin *pungens*, participle of *pungere* "to sting"

***musty*** "Stale or moldy in odor or taste", etymology unknown but possibly based on *moist* (= "wet")

Comment: Does pungent just mean any strong smell? Or maybe it means even not smell, but the activation of pain receptors (like in "hot" food)?

Comment: It does refer to smells -- e.g. the smell of spices such as cinnamon could be described as "pungent".

Comment: so it means just any strong smell, not specific?

Comment: Yes, any "sharp" smell, as the definition above says.

Comment: so it does not count, because I am looking for words for specific smells.

Comment: I don't understand why it would not count. You wrote, *"I am looking for words meaning particular smells, not just 'good smell' or 'bad smell'"*. The word *pungent* refers to a specific type of smell (sharp/strong) and it does not mean "good-" or "bad smelling".

Comment: it does not mean a particular smell, it means any smell if it is strong.

Comment: Couldn't you say by the same logic that the term "mouldy-smelling" does not refer to a particular smell, but rather to any smell as long as it is from a mouldy object? Where are you drawing the line between "particular" and "general" here?

Comment: well if a "mouldy object" means something other than an object smelling mouldy then this also does not count.

Answer (score -1):

In Norwegian you could use two of the same words you used for tastes; sweet(søt) and sour(sur).

You could in fact use that to describe several of the senses:

Det smaker søtt. (It tastes sweet).
Det smaker surt. (It tastes sour).

Det lukter søtt. (It smells sweet).
Det lukter surt. (It smells sour).

Det høres surt. (It hears sour).

Det ser søtt ut. (It looks sweet).
Det ser surt ut. (It looks sour).

This shows me that ( at least for Norwegian) this question is closely related to the general understanding of adjectives and adverbs.

Comment: What does it mean in Norwegian, "It smells sweet"? Does it mean just it smells good or any specific smell?

Comment: I think "sour" is the most protoypic of the two. Yes, "sour" could mean both general and specific. However "meaning" of "smell", is conceptually a bit difficult. Would that mean that most of the language speakers would use that word, when smelling a certain smell? And the other way around, if faced with the same smell, would they use the same word for describing it? "Sour" would probably meet both of these criterias with the smell of used socks.

Comment: Well in Russian I have also encountered "it smells sour", but it seems all people who say so use it arbitrarily, to refer different things, usually either things *tasting* sour or outdated things like rotten/outdated food (in Russian "sour" is synonym to "rotten", so "smelling sour" means just "it smells as if it were rotten/outdated"). I still cannot figure up any specific smell that people would refer to as "sour" because different kinds of rotten food smell differently.

Comment: What is the difference then between the use of "sour" in taste and smell? Isn't both displaying the same relationship between general and specific?

Comment: "Sour" regarding taste means specific thing, the taste of an acid. But acids usually have no smell or have different smells so things that taste sour may have totally different smells. The outdated things while often tasting sour because of acids produced by bacteria (like outdated milk), still do not have a common smelling substance and can smell differently.

Comment: Ok, it seems as your question is then more of a question about senses, then of linguistics. Then I would probably explore the relationship between smell and taste a bit more. Several experiments shows that if you taste food while being prevented from smelling, you will not recognize the taste. So, taste and smell have a very close relationship as senses. Languages will probably just follow along how we interpret that specific relationship.

Comment: there are two kinds of taste: the one about basic tastes (sour, salty, bitter, sweet), the other is more like smell and has a lot of different receptors. But still, I doubt your claims, specifically, how one can prevent one feeling smells? If just blocking the nose, this would not impare tasting at all because tasting receptors are in the mouth and what is needed for tasting is just a substanse dissolved in water in contact with the tongue.

Comment: If you google "taste without smell experiment", then it would give you plenty of references to people exploring this relationship. But, as I said, this is more about science, than linguistics.